# Creating multiple timers in the same thread causes the main thread to lag

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

I am trying to run some code that will enable a variable after 100ms, wait another 100ms and then disable it

I have tried to use 2 timers, and creating a new thread and sleeping it. Both of these solutions cause the main thread to hang for a second or so.

Code i am using for the timers:

```java
                new java.util.Timer().schedule(
                        new java.util.TimerTask() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                PlayerControl.MoveForward = false;
                            }
                        },
                        100
                );
                new java.util.Timer().schedule(
                        new java.util.TimerTask() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                PlayerControl.MoveForward = true;
                            }
                        },
                        200
                );
```

And for the thread approach:

```java
new Thread(() -> {
    Thread.sleep(100);
    PlayerControl.MoveForward = false;
    Thread.sleep(100);
    PlayerControl.MoveForward = true;
})
```

I was expecting both the results of this to wait 100ms, set the variable to false, wait 100ms, then set it to true again, with no impact on the rest of the process. Why is this happening, and how should i be doing this?

Comment: Neither of these would cause the main thread to hand. The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: If this is a Swing program, use a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thread will not exit until all the non-daemon threads are complete.

You can make a timer thread a deamon by doing:

```
            new java.util.Timer(true).schedule(
                    new java.util.TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            PlayerControl.MoveForward = false;
                        }
                    },
                    100
            );
```

As for the ordinary thread, you can do:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
    ...
});
thread.setDaemon(true);
thread.start();
```

Comment: I am unsure why, as the main thread shouldnt be exiting at all, but this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of least modification to your approach, something like this might work:

```
new Thread(() -> {
    Thread.sleep(100);
    PlayerControl.MoveForward = false;
    Thread.sleep(100);
    PlayerControl.MoveForward = true;
}).start();
```

If you want it to run forever, just do something like this:

```
new Thread(() -> {
    for(;;) {
        Thread.sleep(100);
        PlayerControl.MoveForward = false;
        Thread.sleep(100);
        PlayerControl.MoveForward = true;
    }
}).start();
```

If you want to limit the iteration count, just alter the conditions within the `for` loop.

The reason your Thread approach doesn't change anything is that you never started the Thread. As for why your main thread is hanging, that's probably related to the code that you did not post here.

Comment: I did start the thread, i just forgot to paste that part into my code block. Both solutions you have given still cause lag however. I'm going to try Maurice's answer